# PHP Curl login with redirect not working

Tags: php, cookies, curl

I have the following PHP script which should get the content of a page, that is behind a login-form.

It is working fine on my localhost server, but it doesn't work on a host (GoFreeServe). I get an empty response. ($postResult is empty).

Script:

```
    $login_url = 'http://senioren.voetbal.nl/clubs_comp/mijn-teams/competitie/173299/OWIOS-9-zaterdag?destination=clubs_comp%2Fmijn-teams%2Fcompetitie%2F173299%2FOWIOS-9-zaterdag';
$data = file_get_contents("http://voetbal.nl/login/menu/data");
        $parts = explode('name=\"form_build_id\" id=\"',$data,2);
$post_data = 'name=****&pass=****&op=Inloggen&form_build_id='.substr($parts[1],0,37).'&form_id=login_block_login_form';
$ch = curl_init();
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $login_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $login_url );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

$postResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

curl_getinfo Localhost

```
[url] => http://senioren.voetbal.nl/clubs_comp/mijn-teams/competitie/173299/OWIOS-9-zaterdag
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 200
    [header_size] => 557
    [request_size] => 503
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 2.668
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0.016
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.016
    [size_upload] => 57
    [size_download] => 173015
    [speed_download] => 64848
    [speed_upload] => 21
    [download_content_length] => 173015
    [upload_content_length] => 57
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.014
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] =>
```

curl_getinfo Host

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://senioren.voetbal.nl/clubs_comp/mijn-teams/competitie/173299/OWIOS-9-zaterdag
    [content_type] => text/html; charset=utf-8
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 1125
    [request_size] => 361
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 1.001361
    [namelookup_time] => 0.000638
    [connect_time] => 0.094666
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.094712
    [size_upload] => 0
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 0
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 0
    [starttransfer_time] => 1.001199
    [redirect_time] => 0
)
```

The host is not in safe_mode and has CURL installed. Also cookie.txt is chmodded to 777.
The PHPInfo from the host can be found here: http://phpinfo.byethost11.com/index.php

Do you know why I get a http_code of 200 on my Localhost and a http_code of 302 on the host?

Thank you!

EDIT:
After turning on error reporting (!@!#!$) the page returned the following error:

```
Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when safe_mode is enabled or an open_basedir is set in /test2.php on line 39
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by first checking if open_basedir is set.
If that is the case: the script first executes curl_exec() to set the cookies and then executes it again to get the hidden page. Parameters like op and form_build_id aren't used at all :P

Code:

```
if (ini_get('open_basedir') == '') {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10);

    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
} else {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $postResult = curl_exec($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the FOLLOWLOCATION option so it follows the redirect it's getting:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that. Unfortunately it is not working. :(

Comment: Weird, just the other day I saw something similar. Wondering what's causing it :)

Answer (score 0):

`form_build_id`  and `CURLOPT_REFERER` is missing You are suppose to send something like

```
 name=user&pass=pass&op=Inloggen&form_build_id=form-fc3c69bda9d4a9a4a53e70f836ece383&form_id=login_block_login_form
```

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work neither :( Isn't it strange that it works perfectly from my localhost? I've updated the code in the opening post.