# curl request redirects me to localhost page

Tags: php, redirect, curl

I am new to curl and php in general, at the moment I'm trying to get the page source, so I can work with it later.

This is my entire code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$id="3005752358";
$url = "https://www.opendota.com/matches/".$id;
$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

$response = curl_exec ($ch);
 if ($response === false) 
    $response = curl_error($ch);
echo stripslashes($response);
curl_close($ch);
echo "asd";
```

For some reason when I open the page, it redirects me on this url: localhost

There's a similar question from 4 years ago, but it looks like the subject is completely different ( [PHP cURL redirects to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928532/php-curl-redirects-to-localhost) )

Answer (score 1):

Because the response from this URL contains javascript that redirects:

```
<script>
  window.sessionStorage.redirect = window.location.href;
</script>
```

As well as a meta tag that refreshes the page, pointing back to the site root.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='/'"></meta>
```

Try looking at the output in your console, next time since debugging this sort of thing in the browser is only bound to lead to obvious confusion.

Comment: Sure, look at the output from your console, as already suggested, or if you insist on doing in the browser send a `text/plain` Content-type header along with the response from your PHP.

Comment: It looks like this website is protected from viewing its source code, even in browser it returns some small code instead of the actual page source

Comment: No idea how you arrived at that conclusion, but FWIW, this URL clearly returns an HTTP **404 Not Found** status code. You can see that by looking at `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch))`

Comment: Well, this page in browser https://www.opendota.com/matches/3005752358 returns what I need, but its source code in the same browser returns the same small page with  window.sessionStorage.redirect = window.location.href; this code

Comment: It seems to be relying on javascript to resend the request to `https://api.opendota.com/api/matches/3005752358` instead. The server appears to have an Access Control Origin restriction, so yeah. You wouldn't be able to easily get this to work with curl the way you're trying to do it.