# I'm not able to redirect to an external website after curl requests

Tags: php, redirect, curl, https

I successfully do some curl calls to an external website, in fact after the last one I'm able to see the website page I expected to see. The only problem: I'm only able to view this page as an html response, remaining in localhost and the website page is not navigable.
This post ([PHP cURL redirects to localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14928532/php-curl-redirects-to-localhost)) discusses a similar problem, though the solution seems not to work for me.

In particular, this is my code:

```
<?php 

$products = explode(',', $_GET['products']);
$reqheaders = [
    'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language:it',
    'Connection:keep-alive',
    'Host:www.clubpervoi.com',
    'Referer:https://www.website.com/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1',
    'User-Agent:'. $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']
];
$cookie_file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/cookie.txt';


$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


// Action calls
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $params = array('code'=> $products[$i]);
    $query = http_build_query($params);
    try{
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/foo/addProduct?'.$query);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $reqheaders);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e;
    }
}


//Here I expect to be redirected to the summary page
try{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.website.com/foo/summary');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $reqheaders);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

As you can see in the last call I setted

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
```

which in theory will do the trick, but not in my case.

Obviously if I tried to use a

```
header('location https://www.website.com/foo/summary')
```

instead of the last curl call I obtain the error

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...
```

because there is a "conflict" with the previous curl_exec(), though I closed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the conclusion I arrived to: what I wanted to do it's not possible, because I need to use cookies for each curl request.
So I can't "go out" from localhost and landing on the external website to navigate it, because in the moment I exit I invalidate my cookies.