# Follow links with curl/php after login

Tags: php, facebook, curl

I have written a php script using curl to successfully login to facebook.  What I am trying to do is then follow a link to an app on my facebook business page and download a report.  I believe there is a problem with the cookies being passed correctly as my app redirects me to a generic login page when I use curl to follow the link.  Here is the code:

```
<?php
$url='url of my facebook business page';

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:15.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/15.0');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'\cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, dirname(__FILE__).'\cookie.txt');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$fb=curl_exec ($ch);

$lgnrnd=preg_replace('/^.*name="lgnrnd" value="/s','',$fb);
$lgnrnd=preg_replace('/".*$/s','',$lgnrnd);

$lgnjs=preg_replace('/^.*time=/s','',$fb);
$lgnjs=preg_replace('/&amp.*$/s','',$lgnjs);

$login='lsd=AVpAg2yQ&email=myemail&pass=mypass&persistent=1&default_persistent=1&timezone=420&lgnrnd='.$lgnrnd.'&lgnjs='.$lgnjs.'&locale=en_US';

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php?login_attempt=1');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $login);

curl_exec ($ch);


curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://app.com/FacebookSignUpReport.psp?id=1');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_exec ($ch);
?>
```

Comment: does the facebook api not provide the same exact information/ability to pull posts/data that you need? i'm just wondering why you are using curl to begin with when their api is so amazing.

Comment: Not familiar with their api... I have used curl in the past so I just naturally began there.  I'll check out their api while I wait to see if anyone can help with my curl code... thanks.

Comment: it's way easier than trying to parse websites via curl, and it will work for a long time to come instead of simply until they change urls/change the page/etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Curl login with redirect not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12689182/php-curl-login-with-redirect-not-working)